# IllegalAccessError when adding Rampart to the POM's dependencies

Tags: java, classpath, weblogic-10.x, manifest.mf, rampart

We tried adding `Rampart` to our module's POM file and after doing so our `ear` can no longer start with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V from class org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger
        at org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger.<init>(RootLogger.java:43)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:78)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLWatchdog.doOnChange(DOMConfigurator.java:862)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.checkAndConfigure(FileWatchdog.java:88)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.<init>(FileWatchdog.java:57)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLWatchdog.<init>(DOMConfigurator.java:853)
        at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(DOMConfigurator.java:584)
```

`org.apache.log4j.Logger` is defined in two jars - `log4j` and `log4j-over-slf4j`.
In `log4j` - there is a constructor:

```
protected Logger(String name)
```

In `log4j-over-slf4j` there is a constructor:

```
Logger(String name) //Package access only
```

It seems that for some reason `Rampart` triggered a bad classpath order and placed `log4j-over-slf4j` before `log4j`.

However, the most troubling problem is that we were unable to change our `ear`'s manifest to change the order - so eventually we "solved" it by adding the `log4j` jar to the **System Classpath**

My question has two parts:

1. Is the `Rampart` problem familiar and does it have a solution?
2. What reason could it be that
   changing the manifest of the ear
   would not effect the classpath? (I'm
   not that experienced with
   application servers - so obvious
   answers are welcome)

We are using `Weblogic 10.3`, and `Rampart 1.5.1`. We are using `Maven` to compile and build the `ear` file - and I just learned today of a `mar` file, so any inputs about that will also be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually we modified the `pom.xml` manually and changed the order of dependencies to put `log4j` before `rampart` - which solved the classpath order problem.

Comment: I believe even though your log4j-over-slf4j comes from a third-party dependency, you should be able to exclude transitive dependencies via the pom file.

Answer (score 2):

log4j-over-slf4j is replacement of log4j that  proxies to slf4j. This means in your class path you have classes with same name and package, but very different implementation.

Since you use log4j in your system, it is safe to remove log4j-over-slf4j. in that case the library that needs log4j-over-slf4j will actually use the original log4j.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - the problem is that we can't remove `log4j-over-slf4j`, it comes from a 3rd party we must use.

Comment: I had the same issue and this solved my problem. I think it's the correct solution. OP's log4j-over-slf4j can probably be excluded via the pom file.